# Simulating different temperatures on Cooja/Contiki

Tags: c, contiki

I'm having trouble reading different temperature readings on Cooja. I've done the following:

- Created a source file that initializes a light- and temperature-sensor.
- Created a simulation using a Sky mote.
- Ran the simulation with a network of 8 motes.

Each mote reads the same temperature which is useless for what I want. I've spent the last 8 hours looking through threads, documentation (including the Contiki wiki) and haven't been able to come up with anything.

If I'm misunderstanding the way Cooja/Contiki works I'd also appreciate some help with that but, bottom line, how do I simulate different temperatures that can be read by the mote sensors within the simulation environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cooja/MSPsim does not attempt to simulate realistic sensor readings by default. To do that, you'll need to extend the Java code of MSPsim.

Reading the temperature sensor on `sky` simply means reading an ADC port.
This means that to simulate custom readings on that port, you need to set up a custom `ADCInput` on that port.

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/contikiprojects/code/HEAD/tree/uni-erlangen.de/COOJA_SKY_LightSlider/) is a simple example, and [here](https://code.google.com/p/kth-gisoo/wiki/Samples#ADC_data_transmission_in_GISOO_-_Using_Contiki) is an advanced example (that also shows how to simulate DAC).

Code adapted from the first link:

```
private SkyMote skyMote;

private final int MY_VALUE = 123;

protected class MyADC implements ADCInput {
   private int fixedValue;

   public MyADC(int value) {
       fixedValue = value;
   }
   public int nextData() {
       return fixedValue;
   }
}

// temperature sensor on sky is on ADC port 10
IOUnit temperatureADC = skyMote.getCPU().getIOUnit("ADC10");
if (temperatureADC instanceof ADC12) {
   ((ADC12) temperatureADC).setADCInput(4, new MyADC(MY_VALUE));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, worked a charm. For anyone trying out the code, the first link explains the install but is missing a step:

- Add an import for the light sensor at the beginning of SkyMoteType.java

Just as an extra, could you explain what MSP is in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for the z1 mote (heavily modified from the links in kfx's answer):

```
/**
 * @{
 * \file
 *         Method for simulating environmental temperatures for z1 sensors in COOJA
 *         Three temperature simulation methods are included:
 *              - fixed value
 *              - a slider UI that can be set in the Cooja simulation interface
 *              - a mathematical formula that links temperature to position; this
 *                  has the effect of simulating a cold spot in a very hot environment.
 * \author
 *         Dave Hirsch
 */

package org.contikios.cooja.mspmote;


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


import java.util.logging.*;
import org.jdom.Element;

import org.contikios.cooja.ClassDescription;
import org.contikios.cooja.Mote;
import org.contikios.cooja.MoteInterface;
import org.contikios.cooja.MoteInterfaceHandler;
import org.contikios.cooja.interfaces.Position;
import org.contikios.cooja.Simulation;
import org.contikios.cooja.interfaces.Button;
import org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.MspMoteTimeEvent;
import org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.Z1Mote;
import se.sics.mspsim.core.ADC12;
import se.sics.mspsim.core.ADCInput;
import se.sics.mspsim.core.IOUnit;

@ClassDescription("Z1 Temp sensor")
public class Z1TempInt extends MoteInterface {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.interfaces.Z1Temp");
    private static int lastVal = -1;
    private IOUnit adc = null;

    private Z1Mote z1Mote = null;

    protected class ADCfixed implements ADCInput {
        private int fixedVal;
        public ADCfixed(int inp) {
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "In ADCfixed. ");
            fixedVal = inp;
        }

        public int nextData(){
            return fixedVal;
        }

    }

    protected class ADCsliderVal implements ADCInput {
        private JSlider myslider; 

        public ADCsliderVal(JSlider slider){
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "In ADCsliderVal(). ");
            myslider = slider;
        }

        public int nextData(){
            if (myslider == null) {
                return 88;
            } else {
                if (myslider.getValue() != lastVal) {
                    lastVal = myslider.getValue();
                    logger.log(Level.FINE, "DMH-new value: " + myslider.getValue() );
                }
                return myslider.getValue();
            }  
        }
    }

    protected class ADCTempPos implements ADCInput {

        public ADCTempPos(){
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "In ADCTempPos(). ");
        }

        public int nextData(){
            if (getZ1Mote() == null) {
                return 87;
            } else {
                Position pos = getZ1Mote().getInterfaces().getPosition();
                double x = pos.getXCoordinate();
                double y = pos.getYCoordinate();
                return (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y));
            }  
        }
    }

    public Z1TempInt(Mote mote) {
        z1Mote = (Z1Mote) mote;

        try {
            Handler fh = new FileHandler("/home/user/contiki/Z1Temp.log");
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return;
        }
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "Creating Z1Temp object.");
        adc = z1Mote.getCPU().getIOUnit("ADC12");
        String adcClass = adc.getClass().getSimpleName();
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "ADC is:" + adc);
        if (adc instanceof ADC12) {
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "ADC is an ADC12.");
            ((ADC12) adc).setADCInput(10, new ADCTempPos());
        }

    }

    public Z1Mote getZ1Mote() {
        return z1Mote;
    }

    public JPanel getInterfaceVisualizer() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,0));
        final JSlider sADC1 = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 25);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Temperature:"));
        panel.add(sADC1);
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "Setting up panel");
        if (adc != null) {
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "Connecting ADC to slider");
            ((ADC12) adc).setADCInput(10, new ADCsliderVal(sADC1));
        }
        return panel;
    }

    public void releaseInterfaceVisualizer(JPanel panel) {
    }

    public Collection<Element> getConfigXML() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setConfigXML(Collection<Element> configXML, boolean visAvailable) {
    }
}
```