# Simulate data input (sensor read) - Cooja/Contiki

Tags: java, simulation, contiki

I'm new to ContikiOS/Cooja and I'm having some trouble to figure out how to simulate data input.

My question is pretty similar to this one: [Simulating different temperatures on Cooja/Contiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013883/simulating-different-temperatures-on-cooja-contiki)

But there are 2 differences:

- I need data generation to be associated with time, instead of Mote Interface JPanel (As the simulations goes, different data values are generated without the need to interact with Mote Interfaces);
- [Simulating different temperatures on Cooja/Contiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013883/simulating-different-temperatures-on-cooja-contiki) (Advanced example on the first link): I need a simpler version of that.

My ideia is to have a java function that recives 3 arguments: positionX, positionY and time. This function returns a temperature, for example. Or I could load this values from a database.

The point is: this "sensor reads" don't need to be realistic, but I need to have some control over them (Without interacting with Mote Interface)

I've found some examples using the Mote serial port to load the data, but I'm not sure if sending data through a serial port is a good "simulation" of a sensor read.

I'm almost sure that I need to implement ADCinput to achieve my goal, but "where" in the code I should do that ?

Comment: Have you looked into Cooja test scripts as a way of accessing your mote's interfaces?

Comment: After reading the test scripts API, I couldn't find a way to access the mote but through serial interface. I'm not sure if that is a good way to simulate reads. Can I access a db through sql querys using test scripts ?

Comment: Test scripts allow accessing all Java methods of Cooja. You can find your mote interface as documented here: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/3.0/tools/cooja/java/org/contikios/cooja/MoteInterfaceHandler.java#L117 - of course this assumes your simulation has an interface to set a mote's temperature. But you mentioned you already know where to find this.

Comment: After reading a lot about Cooja, Contiki and MSPSIM, I still have some questions (If you @ChristophSommer don't bother to aswer). The "main" question I have in my mind is: where is the best place to find documentation about which sensors I can use in Cooja. The example I linked above is not correct (As I finded out): ADC10 points to mote internal temperature. Skymote sensor temperature (sth11) can be set using an already built in interface (SkyTemperature).

Comment: I've found this datasheet [link]http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~konrad/projects/shimmer/references/tmote-sky-datasheet.pdf for the skymote. There I could find the reference for the STH11(temperature and humidity) sensor.I also found a reference for a S1087 (light) sensor, but I could not find this sensor inside the mspsim project. Did mspsim project implemented this chip ? And a more generic question: Now a days cooja is the best simulator for WSN? Reading through mspsim github repositories, it's seems pretty dead. As new motes comes out, will them be implemented ? Is the project alive ?